# How to paste a valid JS Code as String in Python correctly skipping all possibles characters and without inserting anything?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I need to pass a string to a RPC Call that will be received and compiled as a Javascript on the other side. The problem arrives when my Javascript Code has 2.5mi+ lines, utf8 chars and others that need to be skipped (', `, \', é, ^...).

I already tried using triple quotes and inserting it as a multiline string and replacing \n with '' afterwards, but I'm not sure it worked as my terminal running for 8min+ without producing anything (no error from the RPC side nor from the (my) python side).

```
api = Savoir(rpcuser, rpcpasswd, rpchost, rpcport, chainname)
js = "This would be all my JS Code" 
print(api.create('txfilter', 'nameOfTheFunction', {}, js))
```

[Here's my JS code (smaller to be easier, ~30k lines)](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tloriato/d3aa5df63c12cfec05c9b55f39f7fcfc/raw/51e16c97bc57aa88eb8a77aa2ffc17df1c85dbd1/file.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than pasting it all into your python file, have you considered just straight-up *reading it* from the file it's already in?

```
with open("file.js", 'r') as js_file:
    js = js_file.read()
# you can put a benchmark here to see how long loading the file takes - or to make sure it loaded correctly
...
api.create('txfilter', 'nameOfTheFunction', {}, js)
```

This removes the need to fuss over quote characters, escaped characters, newlines, etc. because they're all exactly how they were in the file - python doesn't *parse* this text, it just *copies* it.

I would also submit that, if your javascript file has any characters that would need to be omitted on the other end, you simply remove them in said file before putting them into your program. It's also possible that it's the API call that's taking a long time to execute, not your own code - you can verify this with `print()` statements placed between each line, or with a debugger.

Comment: rofl, where can I get my certificate of stupidity? thank you!